# searchBarSearchButtonClicked not working IOS

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to use the search bar to print out a string but the delegate function i have written does not work and I really do not understand where I am going wrong. Please can someone advise?

```
 class LandingPage: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{


 func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("search bar button clicked! ")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added the search bar in storyboard then you have to ctrl+drag to ViewController the yellow button and select search bar delegate. if you have created the search bar in code then you have to assign it's delegate in your viewcontroller.swift

```
searchbar.delegate = self
```